# Supabase reach auth helper Auth component does not redirect to the page i want it to

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, supabase

I keep trying to redirect a user to the pricing page after they sign in and this works when it's just email and password, but it starts having issues when it's sign in with Google. Here is the code

```
import { Auth, ThemeSupa } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'
import { useUser, useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { server } from '../config';

const LoginPage = ()=> {
  const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient()
  const user = useUser()
  const router = useRouter()    

  if(user){
    router.push('/pricing');
  }

  if (!user)
    return (
      <div className="auth w-full flex justify-center">
        <div className="justify-center  h-[65vh] mt-11 w-96">
          <Auth
            redirectTo= {`${server}/pricing`}
            appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
            supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
            providers={['google']}
            socialLayout="vertical"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )

}

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: You haven't stated what issue you are having here? what happens when you try to sign in with Google?